# inline style text input

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui

I'm using React with material-ui, I'd like to apply custom css to text in the input, something like:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
<strong color="blue">{value[0]}</strong>
<strong color="red">{value[1]}</strong>
</div>
```

Effectively making something like a rainbow.

I've been playing around with customising input components but haven't figured out how to take complete control of rendering the characters from a value and editing them at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to give style tag instead of color tag so it will be easy to achieve

Just in case if property is dynamic use $ to dynamic value to be insert

Eg style={{color:’red’}} 
For dynamic style={{color:${value}}}

Answer (score 2):

You could [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your `value` string into an array of characters, and loop over this array and render them separately with a color of your choice.

**Example**

```js
const colors = [];
while (colors.length < 100) {
  let color;
  do {
    color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1);
  } while (colors.indexOf(color) >= 0);
  colors.push("#" + ("000000" + color.toString(16)).slice(-6));
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "Foobar"
  };

  onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input value={value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {value.split("").map((char, index) => (
          <strong key={index} style={{ color: colors[index % colors.length] }}>
            {char}
          </strong>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: the problem with his solution is I can still see the old input value, ideally I want the same input area to have the css applied to it.